# Snakemake WorkflowError: Target rules may not contain wildcards

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

```
rule all:
        input:
                "../data/A_checkm/{genome}"

rule A_checkm:
    input:
      "../data/genomesFna/{genome}_genomic.fna.gz"
    output:
        directory("../data/A_checkm/{genome}")
    threads:
        16
    resources:
        mem_mb = 40000
    shell:
        """
        # setup a tmp working dir
        tmp=$(mktemp -d)
        mkdir $tmp/ref
        cp {input} $tmp/ref/genome.fna.gz
        cd $tmp/ref
        gunzip -c genome.fna.gz > genome.fna
        cd $tmp

        # run checking
        checkm lineage_wf -t {threads} -x fna ref out > stdout

        # prepare output folder
        cd {config[project_root]}
        mkdir -p {output}
        # copy results over
        cp -r $tmp/out/* {output}/
        cp $tmp/stdout {output}/checkm.txt
        # cleanup
        rm -rf $tmp
        """
```

Thank you in advance for your help!
I would like to run checkm on a list of ~600 downloaded genome files having the extension '.fna.gz'. Each downloaded file is saved in a separate folder having the same name as the genome. I would like also to have all the results in a separate folder for each genome and that's why my output is a directory.
When I run this code with 'snakemake -s Snakefile --cores 10 A_checkm', I get the following error:

`WorkflowError: Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files or a rule without wildcards at the command line, or have a rule without wildcards at the very top of your workflow (e.g. the typical "rule all" which just collects all results you want to generate in the end).`

Anyone could help me identifying the error, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Q : Target rules may not contain wildcards Error in Snakemake - No wildcards in Target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48671421/q-target-rules-may-not-contain-wildcards-error-in-snakemake-no-wildcards-in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide `snakemake` with concrete values for the `{genome}` wildcard. You cannot just leave it open and expect `snakemake` to work on all the files in some folder of your project just like that.

1. Determine the filenames/genome values of the files which you want to work on, using `glob_wildcards(...)`. See [the documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#how-do-i-run-my-rule-on-all-files-of-a-certain-directory) for further details.
2. Now you can use these values to specify in `rule all` to create all the folders (using your other rule) with those `{genome}` values:

```py
# Determine the {genome} for all downloaded files
(GENOMES,) = glob_wildcards("../data/genomesFna/{genome}_genomic.fna.gz")


rule all:
    input:
        expand("../data/A_checkm/{genome}", genome=GENOMES),


rule A_checkm:
    input:
        "../data/genomesFna/{genome}_genomic.fna.gz",
    output:
        directory("../data/A_checkm/{genome}"),
    threads: 16
    resources:
        mem_mb=40000,
    shell:
        # Your magic goes here
```

If the download is supposed to happen inside snakemake, add a `checkpoint` for that. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74773715/11318472) then.

Comment: Thank you :-) that's exactly what I needed to add " glob_wildcards(...)"