# Snakemake wildcards: Using wildcarded files from directory output

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

I'm new to Snakemake and try to use specific files in a rule, from the `directory()` output of another rule that clones a git repo.

Currently, this gives me an error `Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files: 'json_file'`, and I don't understand why. I have previously worked through the tutorial at https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/workflows-snakemake/index.html.

The difference between my workflow and the tutorial workflow is that I want to *create* the data I use later in the first step, whereas in the tutorial, the data was already there.

Workflow description in plain text:

1. Clone a git repository to path {path}
2. Run a script {script} on every single JSON files in the directory {path}/parsed/ *in parallel* to produce the aggregate result {result}

```py
GIT_PATH = config['git_local_path']  # git/
PARSED_JSON_PATH = f'{GIT_PATH}parsed/'
GIT_URL = config['git_url']

# A single parsed JSON file
PARSED_JSON_FILE = f'{PARSED_JSON_PATH}{{json_file}}.json'

# Build a list of parsed JSON file names
PARSED_JSON_FILE_NAMES = glob_wildcards(PARSED_JSON_FILE).json_file

# All parsed JSON files
ALL_PARSED_JSONS = expand(PARSED_JSON_FILE, json_file=PARSED_JSON_FILE_NAMES)


rule all:
    input: 'result.json'

rule clone_git:
    output: directory(GIT_PATH)
    threads: 1
    conda: f'{ENVS_DIR}git.yml'
    shell: f'git clone --depth 1 {GIT_URL} {{output}}'

rule extract_json:
    input:
        cmd='scripts/extract_json.py',
        json_file=PARSED_JSON_FILE
    output: 'result.json'
    threads: 50
    shell: 'python {input.cmd} {input.json_file} {output}'
```

Running only `clone_git` works fine (if I set an `all` `input` of `GIT_PATH`).

Why do I get the error message? Is this because the JSON files don't exist when the workflow is started?

Also - I don't know if this matters - this is a subworkflow used with `module`.

Comment: You have an open wildcard in `rule extract_json` for `output`, namely `json_file` which is not replaced in the f-string here `PARSED_JSON_FILE = f'{PARSED_JSON_PATH}{{json_file}}.json'`. You need to fix that. Also I wonder about your intentions: Do you want to run `extract_json` on all JSON files together and produce a single output, or is it supposed to run on each json file individually?

Comment: Thank you @euronion! I've just fixed the post to explain more: I want to run `extract_json` on each file individually, and write to an aggregated output. Although perhaps it's better to run `extract_json` and write to one output per JSON file, then aggregate in an extra rule (a checkpoint rule? Just read about those ...).

Can you explain what you mean by an *open wildcard*? I thought wildcards had to be doubly wrapped in curly braces in f-strings?

Comment: Ah, I think I see, *open wildcard* means that I have to use the wildcard in both `input` and `output`? This would then be the second option: produce one result file per JSON file. The question is then: How can I "listen" in `rule all` to the creation of all result files?

Comment: If I use an aggregate var `ALL_RESULTS = expand(RESULT_FILE, json_file=PARSED_JSON_FILE_NAMES)` with one for each result file `RESULT_FILE = 'result.{json_file}.json'`, and use `ALL_RESULTS` as input for `rule all`, the workflow doesn't produce any results, because there are no result files at the start of the workflow.

Comment: By "open" I mean that you do not give `snakemake` enough information such that the value(s) for the wildcard `{json_file}` can be inferred.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't think I quite understand though, sorry. Such f-strings work fine when the data they work on already exist before the workflow is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need seems to be a `checkpoint` rule which is first executed and only then `snakemake` determines which `.json` files are present and runs your extract/aggregate functions. Here's an example adapted:

I'm struggling to fully understand the file and folder structure you get after cloning your git repo. So I have fallen back to the best practices by Snakemake of using `resources` for downloaded and `results` for created files.

You'll need to re-adjust those paths to match your case again:

```py
GIT_PATH = config["git_local_path"]  # git/
GIT_URL = config["git_url"]

checkpoint clone_git:
    output:
        git=directory(GIT_PATH),
    threads: 1
    conda:
        f"{ENVS_DIR}git.yml"
    shell:
        f"git clone --depth 1 {GIT_URL} {{output.git}}"


rule extract_json:
    input:
        cmd="scripts/extract_json.py",
        json_file="resources/{file_name}.json",
    output:
        "results/parsed_files/{file_name}.json",
    shell:
        "python {input.cmd} {input.json_file} {output}"


def get_all_json_file_names(wildcards):

    git_dir = checkpoints.clone_git.get(**wildcards).output["git"]
    file_names = glob_wildcards(
        "resources/{file_name}.json"
    ).file_name
    
    return expand(
            "results/parsed_files/{file_name}.json",
            file_name=file_names,
        )

# Rule has checkpoint dependency: Only after the checkpoint is executed
# the rule is executed which then evaluates the function to determine all
# json files downloaded from the git repo
rule aggregate:
    input:
        get_all_json_file_names
    output:
        "result.json",
    default_target: True
    shell:
        # TODO: Action which combines all JSON files
```

edit: Moved the `expand(...)` from `rule aggregate` into `get_all_json_file_names`.

Comment: Thanks, that's great! To better understand: Because you're using `expand` on the input for `rule aggregate`, this rule is then run for each file individually? Or for all files at once? And if the latter is the case, how would this have to be changed to run for all files individually? Many thanks!

Comment: This still produces a wildcard error: `Building DAG of jobs...
WildcardError in line 43 of /home/user/src/workflow/Snakefile:
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'file_name'`

Comment: The `rule aggregate` runs on all json files (only once, on all files *simultaneously*) which are an output of the `rule extract_json`. This way, `extract_json` runs on all files *individually*.

Comment: Interesting... I've updated the answer and moved the `expand` into the `function`. Seems like that if the function is inside the `expand` (instead of other way around) it does not work. Give it another try with the code changes above!

Comment: Thanks, this works now, and produces the list of JSON files in `rule aggregate`. However, `rule extract_json` is never run (`aggregate` is the default_target). The aim is to run `extract_json` on all files (in the return value of `get_all_json_file_names`) individually (to parallelize later on a cluster). I can't get my head around going from the list of all files to running them individually through `extract_json`...

Comment: I assume you have changed the file paths, right? Did you maybe change the file paths in the `expand(...)` in `get_all_json_file_names(...)` to the path where the `json` files downloaded using `git` reside? That would skip the `extract_json` rule. In the example above, `aggregate` is linked to `extract_json` through the file paths.

Comment: Yes, indeed I have, huh. Now I understand how the two are linked together. Nice! Thanks very much indeed!

Comment: Can I ask one further question, just for my understanding: When you comment "Rule has checkpoint dependency", is this dependency established via the call to `checkpoints.clone_git.get(**wildcards)` in `get_all_json_filenames()``? I would think so, as the rule itself does of course not explicitly refer to `clone_git`... Thanks!

Comment: Yes, correct. With `checkpoints.clone_git` you create the connection to the `checkpoint` in the Snakefile called `clone_git` (your former rule).